# CMAKE target_link_libraries right dylib but won't be found on rpath in runtime

Tags: qt, cmake, dylib

I am trying to build a QT app with cmake, and have a problem including libqsqlite.dylib.
On cmakelist.txt I have the following:

```
foreach(plugin ${Qt5Sql_PLUGINS})
   get_target_property(_loc ${plugin} LOCATION)
   target_link_libraries(myapp PUBLIC ${_loc})
   message("Found plugin ${plugin} at location ${_loc}")
endforeach()
```

I call the config with

```
usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang++ -H/Users/cris/myapp -B/Users/cris/myapp/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

From the message I can see it finds and points to right dylib

```
Found plugin Qt5::QSQLiteDriverPlugin at location /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlite.dylib
```

Then I build with

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/cris/myapp/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 6
```

and everything seems to go fine.

But then when I run I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libqsqlite.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/cris/myapp/build/./myapp
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

And if I call otool -L ./myapp

I can see it there:

```
@rpath/libqsqlite.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
```

At this point I have no idea what is going on and I am very confused..
What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know much about linking under MacOS but maybe this is some chmod issue? Did you check permissions on that library?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I just checked that and it's not the problem..